# How to determine standard deviation of a group of standard deviations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that has the following information:

- Mean of the group
- Number of people in the group
- Standard deviation of the group

So, two entries in this table are:

```
Mean         Std. Dev.       PersonCount
2            1.34            8
1.47         0.618           7
```

What I want to know is how I can get the standard deviation of these two rows using a SQL statement. How can I go about this?

Comment: Can you at least provide the mathematical formula for the standard deviation? There's one to calculate the standard deviation for a population, one for a sample, and one for grouped data (group's sizes are needed).

Comment: You can also check out the `STDEV` function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190474(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I can't provide the formula as I don't know it.  This is a table someone else created.

Comment: I meant the formula for the standard deviation YOU want to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL has a `STDEV()` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190474.aspx) you can use. You can also use the square root, and varaition functions. `SQRT(VAR())`

There are also a lot of other built in [statistical functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634822.aspx) you can use.

Comment: I did that, but I don't think the standard deviation of the standard deviations of 1.34 and 0.618 is 0.36, hence my question.

Comment: It should show the correct value. Proof, I made a Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a4632/1/0  What data type did you use?

Comment: But if the standard deviation for group 1 is 1.34 and the standard deviation for group 2 is 0.618, would the standard deviations of the standard deviations be 0.51?

Comment: I was using stddevp instead of stddev.